# [DJI-SDK][iOS] NEW v3 SDK Demo is not working

Tags: dji-sdk

I downloaded the new SDK demo (v3) from github (https://github.com/dji-sdk/Mobile-SDK-iOS) and opened the project with Xcode 7.2 (7C68).

I'm just api key like described in docs and run application on iPhone 5S iOS 9.2 (13C75). After that I connected phone to remote controller over usb and there's nothing. Nothing changes after several minutes. I can't connect to DJI Phantom 3 Avd with firmware v 16040.

It's look like `sdkManagerProductDidChangeFrom:to:` method not executed at all.

Comment: After iPhone soft reset demo works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DJI iOS SDK 3.0 sample code works for me. I think you should double check the ENTER_DEBUG_MODE Macro value in DJIRootViewController.h file.

If you are using iPhone simulator with [DJI Bridge App](https://github.com/dji-sdk/DJI-Bridge-App), ENTER_DEDUG_MODE should be 1 and please fill your debug id in this line of code:

```
[DJISDKManager enterDebugModeWithDebugId:@"Enter Debug ID Here"];
```

If you are using a real iPhone instead, please ensure that ENTER_DEBUG_MODE is 0.

Lastly, make sure your App Key you apply on [DJI Developer Website](http://developer.dji.com/en/user/apps) is correspond to the demo project's bundle ID: **com.dji.sdkdemo**. And check the app registration result from the following delegate method:

```
-(void) sdkManagerDidRegisterAppWithError:(NSError *)error
```

Make sure there is no error. Hope this help!